# Add properties to model dynamically?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sqlite

I have a following model class:

```
public class Class1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Class1> Class1s{ get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to add one more property to my model that will be

```
public string NewProp { get; set; }
```

I know very well to achieve this by code , but is there any way to add this dynamically?
in simple I want to make a UI who ask me about property name as well as datatype when I submit values it automatically add the property to my existing model. I am using EntityFramework Code-First. However since I have already the DB, I can also use the DB-First approach if the solution is using DB-First.

Comment: So... you want your UI to add to your Entity and then do a migration? Even if this were possible, which its not in any normal sense, this seems like a bad design. what sort of fields are we talking about, just simple string fields or any data type

Comment: It feels like at this point you're moving away from the benefits of Entity Framework, in terms of being able to work with your data safely *in code*. If everything's dynamic, it may be worth going back to data tables etc.

Comment: @TheGeneral I just need a simple string. OK. What if I just want to add it to model without migration? What is the best way in this case?

Comment: Another option is just use a related table with fields like propertyName and value, this would give you a much easier life

Comment: @TheGeneral Can you please explain it in more details?

Comment: If you ever only need to add strings and if you are not going to query on those, you could indeed add a key-value table (EAV pattern). But bear in mind this is a known sql antipattern.

Comment: @mstaessen OK. I want to know how? How to add a key-value or a dictionary table in run-time? can you give me a reference or example about this?

Comment: This has been discussed before: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bentity-framework%5D+eav

Comment: since EF constructs the model from the assembly classes via reflection, you'd have to inject this property into the type so EF can get it. However, even if this is possible, you'll probably need to step back from automated migrations as EF can't determine the shape of the migration at compile time

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/168269). Try to explain on a somewhat higher level what you're trying to achieve. What you propose is a dead end. Maybe EAV is the best option here. Maybe storing XML or Json. Maybe you should turn to a NoSql database.

Comment: @GertArnold I would go with Gert Soultion, Since you want dynamic structure from UI, Then let the user design what he wants, at the end take it as JSON or XML. In this case you have a dynamic one, you can deserilize it and show it to the user again and again,